# Git push to bare repository not reflecting changes

Tags: git, bash, atlassian-sourcetree

On my local machine I have a `dev` branch and a `prod` branch of a `master` repository in bitbucket. This master repository is `origin` on my local remotes.  I also have a webserver that's hosted as a `bare repository` to push changes to. This bare repository is `prod-server` on my local remotes.

#### When I push the contents of `prod` to `prod-server master` the production server tells me `Everything up-to-date`; but, if I check the webserver's files, their changed timestamp and contents do not reflect the changes in my commit!

#### Git-bash

```
kareem.elashmawy@domain.com MINGW32 /c/git/ObfuscatedProjectName (prod)
$ git push prod-server prod:master -f
Password:
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 445 bytes | 445.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
To ssh://prodserver.com/ObfuscatedProjectName
   d24b1492..1898d38c  prod -> master

kareem.elashmawy@domain.com MINGW32 /c/git/ObfuscatedProjectName (prod)
$ git push prod-server prod:master -f
Password:
Password:
Everything up-to-date
```

#### git log on server

```
commit 1898d38c67a1c35c30e002a4bc53b161973a944e
Author: Kareem Elashmawy <kareem.elashmawy@domain.com>
Date:   Fri Sep 22 18:59:07 2017 -0400

    second commit today

commit d24b14928f3c0b950a2d1a09958bce3e6659386e
Author: Kareem Elashmawy <kareem.elashmawy@domain.com>
Date:   Fri Sep 22 18:34:53 2017 -0400

    first commit today

commit e0de2b25d1cffb583f4a4b1fccbd88416ddac79f
Author: Kareem Elashmawy <kareem.elashmawy@domain.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 21 18:02:51 2017 -0400

    yesterday's commit
```

ls -l on server

```
[kareem@domain python]$ ls -l
total 748
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache company    2126 Jul 21 15:36 file.py
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 kareem kareem  1733 Sep 21 17:18 file2.py
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache company    1461 Sep 21 17:44 file3.py
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache company   27257 Jul 21 15:36 file4.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   22597 Jul 25 11:50 file5.pyc
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache company    1458 Sep 21 18:08 file6.py
```

Notice the time stamps for files 3,4, and 5? They correspond to yesterday's commit, but were changed in today's 2 commits. If I open the files directly and check their contents, they are indeed unchanged since yesterday in spite of the git log specifying otherwise.

#### /ObfuscatedProjectName/hooks/post-receive

```
#!/bin/sh 
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ObfuscatedProjectName git checkout -f
```

Comment: A bare repository does not have a working folder, thus no files are checked out from the repository. Pushing to a bare repository should only affect the repository **not any files in a working folder**, this is what "bare" means. Can you clarify what you are doing here? If you have a bare repository then no other files should be affected by a push (which is what you're complaining about), but if you have a non-bare repository then you should not (by default) be able to push to it. Can you explain **exactly** what your scenario is?

Comment: To be specific, it seems your expectations are wrong. Can you clarify?

Comment: updated with post-receive hook in bare-repository. It looks like the directory was wrong. `/home/ObfuscatedProjectName` instead of /ObfuscatedProjectName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A post-receive hook had been setup to checkout the repository upon receipt of commits. The directory url was wrong.

```
#!/bin/sh 
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ObfuscatedProjectName git checkout -f
```

`/home/ObfuscatedProjectName` should've been `/ObfuscatedProjectName`